# Reload data of UITableView in background/foreground at specific time

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6, uilocalnotification

In my application, I have a `UITableViewController`.
I need to reload the data of tableview daily morning at 12:01AM whether my application is in background or foreground. I think using local notification its possible, but I don't know how to do. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Do you have any code?

Comment: Is that data really needs to be reloaded at 12:01AM, even if user will not immediately see that data due to a background state of application?

Comment: Yes, its really needs to be reload bcoz I have written some code in cellForRowAtIndexPath So i should reload the table at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use remote notifications to wake the app up at a scheduled time. You can then use:
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler`

This will be called when the application receives a remote notification. You will put your table view reloading code in here.

You can use a web service such as Parse.com or UrbanAirship to schedule a notification to be sent at a specific time

Sources: [Apple Developer Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) 
         [Notifications Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)